# Android Room - Sum up values and put it in TextView

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

Maybe this is a tiny bit stupid to ask but I am just stuck with this:

I have my Room Database + Entities + Daos.

The entities have a column called "costs" - so basically I wanna sum up all the costs (of course while tracking if there was a new input, so check if the sum has changed - if so, of course change the value/textview) and then simply put the value with .toString() into a TextView.

I already have a RecyclerView+CardView with an Adapter / ViewModel / Repository Class (they put only the Names of the Input into the CardView)

I just don't know where to put the costs stuff - I don't think I need a new ViewModel/Repository but where do I put the sumAllCost() method of my Dao

```
public class SubRepository {

private SubDAO mSubDao;
private LiveData<List<Sub>> mAllSubs;

SubRepository(Application application){
    SubDatabase db = SubDatabase.getInstance(application);
    mSubDao = db.getsubDAO();
    mAllSubs = mSubDao.getAllSubs();
}

public LiveData<List<Sub>> getAllSubs(){
    return mAllSubs;
}

public void insert (Sub sub){
    new insertAsyncTask(mSubDao).execute(sub);
}

private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Sub, Void, Void> {
    private SubDAO mAsyncTaskDao;

    insertAsyncTask (SubDAO dao){
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Sub... params){
        mAsyncTaskDao.addSub(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

---

```
public class SubViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private SubRepository mRepository;

private LiveData<List<Sub>> mallSubs;

public SubViewModel (Application application) {
    super (application);
    mRepository = new SubRepository(application);
    mallSubs = mRepository.getAllSubs();
}

public LiveData<List<Sub>> getAllSubs(){
    return mallSubs;
}

public void insert (Sub sub){
    mRepository.insert(sub);
}}
```

---

```
class HomeSubAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeSubAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<Sub> subList;
Context context;
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

HomeSubAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


//Just wanna show the name so only one tv
public class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView main_cv_dummy;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        main_cv_dummy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_cv_dummy);


    }
}





@Override
public HomeSubAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View subview = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_main_cardview, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(subview);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (HomeSubAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (subList!= null){
        final Sub current = subList.get(position);
        holder.main_cv_dummy.setText(current.getSubName());

        holder.main_cv_dummy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Fragment currentFrag = ShowInfoFragment.newInstance(current);
                //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.compLayout, currentFrag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                Log.d("Clicking: ", current.getSubName() + " was clicked - Listener worked");
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        holder.main_cv_dummy.setText("Create a new Sub!");
    }

}

public void setSubs(List<Sub> subs){
    this.subList = subs;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}






@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    if(subList!=null){
        return subList.size();
    } else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

The Activity with onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting");
    middle_vf = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.middle_vf);

    tv_sum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_sumCosts);




    mSubViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SubViewModel.class);

    mSubViewModel.getAllSubs().observe(this, new Observer<List<Sub>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Sub> subs) {
            mAdapter.setSubs(subs);

        }
    });


    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    //Whenever screen is called - call for recycler view
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_rv);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);




    //give dummy-subs to Adapter to Recycler
    mAdapter = new HomeSubAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    setupBottomNavigationView();
    setupFAB();

}
```

---

I am really not sure about this whole SUM thing

```
//Get all costs
@Query("SELECT SUM(costs) FROM subscriptions")
void getAllCosts();

//Get all subs
@Query("SELECT * FROM subscriptions")
LiveData<List<Sub>> getAllSubs();
```

---

Maybe someone can help - I feel rather stupid right now sorry! I already search several times for a fitting solution but I just cannot find something that helps me (or that I understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should provide an alias name to the synthetic column (it might even work without that, but in general, it is easier to access column-names of domain aggregate function results like that):

```
SELECT SUM(costs) AS value FROM subscriptions
```

and when a query is expect to return something `void` (nothing) cannot be used, that should be the actually returned data-type instead; for monetary values and `LiveData`, try `LiveData<BigDecimal>`. the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#extend_livedata) also has one relevant example, which might explain it in more detail.