# sum() function of Sqlite does not seem to work as expected with room persistence library

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

I want to calculate sum of weight field of all records in table, I tried:

In Dao class

```
@Dao
interface FooDAO {
    @Query("SELECT sum(purchaseWeight) FROM myTable")
    suspend fun calculateSumOfAllWeight(): Int    
}
```

In repository class

```
class FooRepository(application: Application) {

    private var fooDAO: FooDAO

    private var sumOfAllWeight = MutableLiveData<Int>()

    init {
        // skipping other code
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
             sumOfAllWeight.postValue(fooDAO.calculateSumOfAllWeight())
        }
    }

    fun getSumOfAllWeight(): MutableLiveData<Int> {    
        Log.e("SUM_OF_WEIGHT", " sumOfAllWeight "+ sumOfAllWeight.value)
        return sumOfAllWeight    
    }    
}
```

but It prints

```
E/SUM_OF_WEIGHT: sumOfAllWeight null
```

in the logcat, I have referred [This Link](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/tryit/query/sqlite-sum/#1) for working with sum() in sqlite.

### Update

I have searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54514662/1056042) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802209/1056042)SO posts and updated

```
@Query("SELECT sum(purchaseWeight) as value FROM myTable")
suspend fun calculateSumOfAllWeight(): Int
```

and found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54930984/1056042) and updated

```
@Query("SELECT COALESCE(sum(COALESCE(purchaseWeight,0)), 0) From myTable")
suspend fun calculateSumOfAllWeight(): Int
```

but still the same `null` is returned

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate functions in sql return null when the table is empty. Only the COUNT function returns 0. You also read the value of a LivaData which is updated asynchronously and you are not sure that the query has already been executed. Try putting a log in the init block after the suspend function to test the returned value.